# Hide DIV in loop function JavaScript Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to hide the slideshow as well as slideshow DIVs unless the button is clicked? I have tried using the onClick function but it comes out with an error with the functions, used a clicked(); event listener, but nothing happens, and even then with those some of DIVs don't hide by default (like the dots and slideshow navigators). Could you please find a way to hide all the slide show DIVs unless the flute button is clicked? Thanks! (Previous one has error with function)

***I have already tried hiding it through CSS, and using an onClick event listener but they do not work.**

```js
function onClick(){

    let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls n = number selected in arrows
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(nu) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = nu);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  //makes i variable, gets slides and dots on slideshow
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

//n = number inputted/selected


  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  
    for  (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
   }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  


  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 }
}
```

```css
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    /*box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.9rem #525c5c, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;*/
    
    z-index: 100;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;   /* ADD */
  }
  
  .wrapper:hover {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px lightgray;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-duration: 0.2s; 
  }
  
  .wrapper .image {
    overflow: hidden;            /* ADD */
    border-radius: 1rem;         /* ADD */
  }
  
  .wrapper .image img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
     border-radius: 1rem;      /*REMOVE */
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s;    /* ADD */
  }
  
  .wrapper:hover img {          /* change scale? */
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  
  .wrapper .infocontent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-shadow: .5px 1px 4px rgb(32, 21, 21);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Consolas;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #441d9e;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover{
  background-color: rgba(53, 49, 49, 0.37);

} 
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(53, 49, 49, 0.37);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
  
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" >
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/02/06/lens/06xp-flute1/06xp-flute1-jumbo-v2.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp" title = "Golden Flute Background (possibly article?)" onclick = "onClick();">
        </div>
        <div class="infocontent">
          <h3><strong>Golden Flute</strong></h3>
        </div>
      </div>

<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container" >

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade" >
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
   <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/02/06/lens/06xp-flute1/06xp-flute1-jumbo-v2.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
     <!-- <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">-->
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
     <!--<img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%"> -->
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
  
    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)" id = "dot1"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)" id = "dot2"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)" id = "dot3"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have converted your code in the question into a snippet so we can test it on-the-fly. But I would like to kindly ask you to make sure that the problem is easy-to-reproduce and please also provide easy-to-understand reproduction steps. Thanks!

Comment: I see you have edited your question, but whenever I click on a paging icon, I get a `"ReferenceError: currentSlide is not defined"` error. Do you get this error in your browser as well?

Comment: Yes, for some reason my functions aren't being ran while using the onClick attribute in my image div. @LajosArpad

Comment: I have implemented an answer, which is probably not fulfilling 100% your expectations (I'm not sure I understand all the intentions correctly), but it should significantly help you find the answer. The inner functions defined inside `onClick` were invisible outside the closure of `onClick`, i.e. from the click handler. I have done a quick refactoring to illustrate how to make them operational, but I'm not sure what should exactly happen inside `onClick`, so I added an alert there.